# what do i need to plug in my android and my guitar in one amp

Tags: electric-guitar

what I am trying to do is to play beat off my android RC-10 and play my guitar all on one amp. I don't have much money so I cant be buy all sorts of gears. I have a chord for my android to the amp,I just look for something I can plug in both in to on amp.

Comment: It depends on the amp. Some have two or more inputs and then you just need the right cables. What amp do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you have one input on your amp. Buy a jack splitter plug, which is one male and two females. Plug guitar lead (cable) into one, and using a 3.5mm>1/4" adapter, plug your phone into the other. None will sound great, but for less than £10, it'll work.

Comment: I'm not actually sure this will work. The gain required for the guitar may be large enough that even at its lowest output volume setting the Android will be too loud.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - just tried, albeit with md. and guitar, and each worked at a sensible volume independently, but couldn't get them working together. Don't know why!

Answer (score 1):

You could plug them both into your computer and use it as a mixer.  Or, if you could scrounge up $50, you could get a small mixer.